# Javascript Canvas returning wrong RGB values (offset red by 1)

Tags: javascript, canvas, rgb

I have an application that involves pixel-perfect manipulation of PNGs loaded into a Canvas and manipulated.

I've noticed that in 'some but not all' instances the Red value from an RGB set is returned/displayed one point higher than the original PNG.

To demonstrate I've put a code pen together for a number of color swatches.

Pen: https://codepen.io/V3Dev/pen/jOWNKLN

File: https://i.ibb.co/5jZ9BTM/red-Swatches.png

The test in question is a simple getImageData:

```
function getItemFromHitTest(x, y) {
    let pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    let color = `rgb(${pixel[0]},${pixel[1]},${pixel[2]})`;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = color;
    //console.log(x,y,color);
}
```

When you click on a color block you see the returned value - which is correct for pure-red (255,000,000) and values up to (112,000,000) however the value (113,000,000) onwards is being returned as (114,000,000) which is what I don't understand and is causing my problems.

I'm unsure if this an issue with the PNG file (unlikely as I can open it with both Paint and Photoshop and they both agree on the RGB value and there is no alpha-channel for the file) or with the javascript processing of the canvas. Insights welcome.

Comment: It has gAMA and cHRM chunks. Probably related. Not sure if it’s rounding error or if the browser doesn’t support different colorspaces. Or maybe the original values aren’t measured in the display space and it’s doing the conversion for you. Might be necessary to include a PNG decoder of your own?

Comment: For the codepen link I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: OffscreenCanvas".

Comment: OffscreenCanvas might not be a function supported by all browsers - can you try Chrome?

Comment: @Ry, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by gAMA and cHRM chunks. Can you elaborate a bit please? Are these non-visible aspects of the PNG file?

Comment: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.Anc-color, specifying the colorspace of the pixel values in the PNG in the absence of any other better specifiers (which aren’t present in your example PNG).

Comment: Chrome on Mac OS shows the labelled values up to 111, from 112 onward they're +1 for red.

Comment: Interesting read - and I suspect you're on the right path. I swapped out the file to a bitmap and it solved the problem - unfortunately the size went from 15k to 2mb so that's not a great option but it gives me some things to work with. Cheers

Comment: @RobG, yeah that's the problem - not behaving as expected! Based on Rys comment it appears to be a function of PNG 'extra' data not contained within the pixel information but possibly overlaid at a file level.

Comment: You don't need a bmp file. You just need a PNG with only RGB colorspace specified. Non-RGB colorspace may give different results on different computers because it may trigger code that take into account your monitor calibration values which means different conversions to RGB on different hardware (especially on Macs which automatically have colorspace profiles even when not manually calibrated)

Comment: Sometimes you can get pure RGB files in some software by saving for "web" or "web optimized"